# How to punch in a text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have a text and white paths above it. I need to 'crop' the text with the paths...
Similar to the "punch" of adobe fireworks.
How I do this?
thanks

[image]

Comment: [This](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-punch-through-all-the-layers-in-adobe-illustrator) question has answers that should solve your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways: actually subtracting your white path from the text shape, or creating a clipping or opacity mask.

#### Subtracting from the text shape

Since Illustrator doesn't see text objects as shapes, you'll have to <kbd>Object > Expand</kbd> your text object to a shape first. This has the side effect of your text not being editable as text anymore. Ungroup the text (expanding creates a group of objects, each letter being a single object), and then use the `Pathfinder` palette to punch out your shapes.

#### Creating a clipping mask

- Group your text if it's multiple objects;
- Create a shape covering all of your text;
- Punch out the white shapes from this shape;
- Remove fill and stroke from the shape;
- Select both the 'empty' shape and your text group;
- Choose <kbd>Object > Clipping Mask > Make</kbd>.

#### Creating an opacity mask

See [this question and answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-punch-through-all-the-layers-in-adobe-illustrator). Thanks, Jenna.